# c++ memory leak on my data structure

Tags: c++

So I've graduated from learning C and now learning C++. From what I understand C and C++ are similar in variety of ways so I'm trying to re-write my past C project files into C++. However I keep getting a memory leak when I try to print out my information. Can someone tell me why I am getting a memory leak in my code.

### struct.h

```
typedef struct student_info {
    char last[10];
    char first[10];
    int student_id;
    int count_student;
} student;

typedef struct course_info {
    char name[10];
    int course_id;
    int count_course;
    student *students;
} course;

typedef struct gradebook_info {
    course *courses;
} gradebook;
```

### function.c

```
void new_course(gradebook *info) {
    int i, loop=0;

    cout << "Enter Number of Courses " ;
    cin >> loop;

    for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {

        cout << "Enter Course ID ";
        cin >> info->courses[info->courses->count_course].course_id;

        cout << "Enter Course Name ";
        cin >> info->courses[info->courses->count_course].name;

        info->courses->count_course++;

    }
}

void new_student(gradebook *info) {
    int i, loop=0;

    cout << "Enter Number of Students " ;
    cin >> loop;

    for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {

        cout << "Enter Student ID ";
        cin >> info->courses->students[info->courses->students->count_student].student_id;

        cout << "Enter Last Name ";
        cin >> info->courses->students[info->courses->students->count_student].last;

        cout << "Enter First Name ";
        cin >> info->courses->students[info->courses->students->count_student].first;

        info->courses->students->count_student++;
    }
}

void printCourse(gradebook *info) {
    int i;

    cout << "Course ID\tCourse Name\t" << endl;

    for(i=0; i<info->courses->count_course; i++) {

        cout << info->courses[i].course_id << "\t\t";
        cout << info->courses[i].name << endl;
    }
}

void printStudent(gradebook *info) {
    int i; 

    cout << "Student ID\tLast Name\tFirst Name\t" << endl;

    for(i=0; i<info->courses->students->count_student; i++) {

        cout << info->courses->students[i].student_id << "\t\t";
        cout << info->courses->students[i].last << "\t\t";
        cout << info->courses->students[i].first << endl;
    }
}
```

- When I run `new_course()` function it works.
- I run my `printCourse()` function it works.
- I run `new_student()` function it works.
- When I run `printStudent()` function it works.
- Then I try to run `printCourse()` function again and when `i=2`, I get some information from my struct student.

I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

### main.c

```
gradebook *info = new gradebook; //allocate memory

do {
    main_menu();

    int option=0;

    switch(option) {
        case 1: new_course(info);
            break;
        case 2: new_student(info);
            break;
        case 3: printCourse(info);
            break;
        case 4: printStudent(info);
            break;
    }
}while(option < 13);

delete(info);
```

Comment: What information do you get?

Comment: Please post your `main()` function so that we can see how you allocate memory for your `gradebook`

Comment: @user2816227 I think you are using the term "memory leak" incorrectly. A memory leak is the result of allocating memory (such as via `new` in c++ or `malloc()` in c), and not making the proper deallocation call (`delete`, `free()`) when that memory is no longer required (or... ever). Given the lack of any allocations in your code, a leak is not possible.

Comment: In the answer to this question, please also talk about the insanity with how `info->courses->count_course` and `info->courses->students->count_student` is used.

Comment: Rewriting C as C++ involves more than swapping `printf` for `cout`. You need to turn those structs into C++ized classes and start using higher level data structures such as STL containers.

Comment: what do you mean you are leaking - how do you know that?

Comment: Another point, c++ structs are automatically typedefed, so using the keyword at best is useless and might even throw error depending upon compiler

Comment: I apologize I didn't think to write my main function. It is now Included.

Comment: Now that you've provided your `main()`... please describe the problem you're having, but this time do it without using the term "memory leak" -- you're not experiencing a memory leak and you have not explained what the symptoms of your issue are.

Comment: When you allocate memory for your `gradebook` then you only allocate memory for a pointer to a `course`. You never allocate memory for the course itself. The same happens for the `student`...

Comment: I'm still new to C++ So I'll try to explain my problem the best as I can. When I add information inside my courses and students and try to run my print functions I get information from students printing in courses.

Comment: If you want to go the `C++` route, then `gradebook` should not have a `course*` but a `std::vector<course>`, `course` should have have a `student*` but a `std::vector<student>`, and in `student` names shouldn't be `char[10]` but `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not only to allocate memory for the `gradebook`, but also for the `courses` and the `students`. For example:

```
gradebook *info = new gradebook;
info->courses = new course_info[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    info->courses[i]->students = new student_info[10];
```

Beware, this example limits the number of courses and students per course to 10.

P.S.: Your code might work for one or two iterations if you don't allocate memory for the `courses` and the `students`. But in this case you screw up your memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the pointers `students` and `course` using `new`.

After getting loop:

`students = new student_info* [loop]`
and

`courses= new course_info* [loop]`